# How to set a text format to a views fields

Tags: 7, views, input-formats

If you add a content:body field to a view, you got several formatter options: default, plain text, trimmed, summary or trimmed. But is there a way to apply regular text filters?

I stumbled upon this while making an rss feed. Plain text formatter fails to remove brackets media module inserted into the article text.